# How to retrieve array value in promise? (Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'tabId' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension, promise

I am developing my chrome extension. I can't retrieve the array value in promise.

```
async function getAllTabs() {
    let allTabs = [];

    await chrome.windows.getAll({populate: true},function(windows){
        windows.forEach(function(window){
            window.tabs.forEach(function(tab){
                let url = new URL(tab.url);

                allTabs.push({windowId: window.id.toString(), tabId: tab.id.toString(), domain: url.hostname, title: tab.title, url: tab.url});

            });
        });
    });

    return allTabs;
}

let allTabs = getAllTabs();

allTabs.then(function(tabs) {
        console.log(tabs); // no prob, an array is shown
        console.log(tabs[0].tabId); // error! Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'tabId' of undefined
});
```

[Console Log for tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HLvD.png)

But I can get the values for simple dictionary array.

```
let dictArray = [];
dictArray.push({tabId: 2, windowId: 3, msg: "Hello"});
dictArray.push({tabId: 8, windowId: 6, msg: "Kitty"});
console.log(dictArray); // an array is shown
console.log(dictArray[0].tabId); // 2
```

Comment: does `chrome.windows.getAll` return a Promise? not many functions that return a Promise also take a callback - so, `await`ing a function that does NOT return a Promise won't wait for the asynchronous process at all, therefore you are returning an empty array

Comment: Yes. It returns a promise. After "then", an array is shown.

Comment: I bet it doesn't ... the problem is, the console can lie to you ... the fact that `no prob, an array is shown` doesn't mean that the array was there at that point in the code ... try this if you don't believe me ... `console.log(tabs.length)` - I bet it shows ZERO ... hmm, maybe not, but give it a try

Comment: Yes. You are right. It is zero. So what can I do to get the array value?

Comment: first, you need to realise that `chrome.windows.getAll` does NOT return a promise ... change your code to `let x = chrome.windows.getAll ..... etc` then `console.log(x)` - if that doesn't log a Promise object, then you need to rethink how you'll "wait" for that asynchronous operation to conclude

Comment: Yes. You are right. chrome.windows.getAll does NOT return a promise. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think this replacement for `getAllTabs` will help - https://pastebin.com/1B0bAwGA - note, doesn't need `async/await` because it returns a Promise, and doesn't need to await any other Promises

Comment: Yes. You are right again. It works! Pls post your answer!!